# Is there a kerf or shave-off modifier?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, edit-mode

Is there a modifier which "shaves" off 0.1m of every face equally? As if it were to go over every face and move it 0.1m in the negative normal direction, and clipping it properly. Displacement seems almost it, but it warps the shape unequally.

Resizing doesn't do the trick either.

Edit: I'm trying to make this keyboard 'Enter' key work. All of the other keys have the same displacement modifier. As you can see the enter key gets a weird dent from the displacement modifier.

[image: Enter key in Edit-mode]

[image: Enter key displacement result]

Answer (score 3):

The displacement modifier works like I want it to when I make sure that the co-planar faces are not divided, i.e. by doing a limited dissolve first, to turn the quads of the enter key into ngons.

Comment: Good to know, thanks for posting your answer.. I'd really like to figure out why this works :)

Comment: @RobinBetts My guess: perhaps it goes through the faces sequentially, and it does the middle face first. Because of that the other faces become diagonal, and then it scales those in their now diagonal normal direction. EDIT: nope, that doesn't seem to be it either.

Answer (score 2):

If you select the faces you want to be displaced along their normals, and use <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> *Shrink/Fatten* with 'Offset Even' checked, that should do the trick. You can numerically enter the offset.

[image]

Thee internal edges don't quite know where to go, but they could be snapped or 0-scaled back into place.

Comment: ..to select the side faces only, select 1 top and 1 bottom face, Shift-G select coplanar, and Ctrl-I invert the selection.

Comment: This is too manual for my taste. What if I ever have a really big mesh? Or what if I want to adjust the parameters if I later on decide on fatter/leaner keys? I'd have to manually redo it every time. Selecting all faces still gives the same distortion as a displace modifier. So I have to go by each face.